# Apache Maven installation in window 8

Tags: java, maven

Actually I tried to install Apache Maven to my system.

I followed these steps:

1. Downloaded **apache-maven-3.3.3** in my Window 8 machine and copied to **`Program Files`**.
2. Then added maven path **`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3`** as `M2_HOME` in system variable and added **`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`** as `JAVA_HOME`.
3. Then added `;%M2_HOME%\bin` to default Path.
4. Then tried to run as `mvn -version` in CMD.

But I got the result like:

> mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: Did you restart cmd? A process sees environment variables and their values, as they were at the start of this process.

Comment: yaa.. restarted my cmd and type the command .but still showing the same alert

Comment: Then it's likely spaces in paths. Instead of bothering with quotes (and potential bugs in some program's path handling), I would just use spaceless paths.

Comment: I checked but  there is no space issue ..

Comment: check your environment variables and see how it resolved the path.  Go for paths without spaces (for anything really).  This is not a programming question but a question on windows OS.

Comment: You may be running into a windows security issues, Try to create a folder outside of "program files" like `c:\installations` put maven there and set the enviroment  variables to this new path and try it. Remember to restart the console. If it still not work, restart the computer (default windows solution).

Comment: Does **cd %M2_HOME%** work (you navigate to the Maven directory)? What exactly does **echo %PATH%** print out?

Comment: add `apache-maven-3.3.3\bin` to the `PATH` and see the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember I had similar issue some time ago on Windows 7. On Windows 8 it may behave similarly. Your solution should work correctly, but for some reason it's not working.

Add path to `bin/` directory inside your Maven directory to the `Path` system variable after semicolon. In your case it will be:

`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin`

Save `Path` variable, close terminal, run it again and type: `mvn -version`.

Comment: He did it: `Then added " ;%M2_HOME%\bin" to default Path`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I know. I had the same problem some time ago and even after adding `;%M2_HOME\bin"` to the `Path` variable for some reason Windows couldn't recognize Maven in command line interface. That's why I tried to add direct path without any variables to make it working.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen late comment, but if you really did what you commented there then it is no wonder that it didn't work, its missing a % sign :) Quite possibly things may go wrong if you have environmental variables defined separately as user variables and system variables.

Comment: @Gimby You may be right and it could be useful information for the future problem solvers. I can't verify that now, because I use different computer with different OS.